# NetComm modem reports no internet connection despite the PC still has internet access

Tags: modem

I switched to use a NetComm modem. Since I use it purely as a modem, I turned off its Wi-Fi to avoid interference with my other Wi-Fi access point.

Here is the web image:

[image]

I don't understand why there is a red cross next to 'Internet' and a red mark 'Wired Device'.

In other part of the admin console, there is no listing of my PC, despite it is connected to the modem and has an active connection.

I want to define port forwarding to/from the PC. Without its presence in the GUI I am unable to define such rules.

How can I fix this modem problem?

Comment: Is the PC connected over wifi or directly to the modem? is the AP running its own DHCP server or using the one off the gateway?

Comment: PC is connected to the modem directly via a network cable; the wifi AP is a Google Wifi, so yes it runs its own DHCP